# ruby wont read output of ffmpeg

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg

running

```
a = `ffmpeg -i video.mp4`
```

does not seem to give the output of the command into `a`... Why is that? how do override it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

```
a = `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1`
```

**Detailed answer:**

When I ran `ffmpeg -i blah.avi` on a handy file, I noticed that none of its output when out to standard out; instead, all the output when to standard error. You can check yourself at the shell by running:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 > /tmp/standard_out 2> /tmp/standard_error
```

Then look at both `/tmp/standard_out` and `/tmp/standard_error`. You'll see which one is which quickly. You can quickly 'fix' this by using `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1` in your script, which will ask the shell to redirect stderr along with stdout. You won't be able to tell the difference between stderr and stdout, but you can get the output you 'see' easily enough.

You'll have to use [popen3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html#M001644) if you want to keep stdout and stderr separate.